# Javascript: trivial lib for writing game-style skill tree graphs

Tags: javascript, graphics, graph

**I want** to do something like [this skill tree](http://www.dungeonsanddevelopers.com/). What I dislike about that beautiful graph is that background is a standard Photoshop layout, and to change that skill tree I need to rewrite a layout.

**Question:** Can you suggest me a javascript lib which will satisfy 2 requirements:

1. Can build a beautiful graph
2. Is pretty easy to customize (i.e. replace connection arrows style, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be looking for this: https://github.com/352Media/skilltree, it's made with Knockout.js.